# Leaflet Map disappears when selecting term in views exposed filter

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, javascript

I'm using [leaflet](https://www.drupal.org/project/leaflet) in a content view with a page having an exposed filter on taxonomy terms.

Problem is whenever a term/filter is selected and applied the map disappears and turns grey. 
I'm using Leaflet More Maps and this seems to happens with any map.

Comment: is term/filter having data? if not please select show map when there is no data.

Comment: Yes there is data. There are nodes created with the selected terms... The map disappears and shows as a blank grey box.

Answer (score -1):

You must use global area views from other block with generic map, should not have results always show you the map.